# Adding Primary Keys in T-SQL

Tags: t-sql, primary-key

In a T-SQL tutorial I´ve seen that there are two different ways (at least) of creating or adding a primary key constraint to a table, one of them being making an alteration on the pre-existing table (Customer):

```
USE RoomReservation;
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.Customer ADD CONSTRAINT
     PK_Customer PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (CustomerId);
```

and the other one being at the moment of creation of the Customer table itself:

```
USE RoomReservation;
GO
CREATE TABLE dbo.Customer (
    CustomerId INT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT PK_Customer PRIMARY KEY,
    FirstName NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
    LastName NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL);
```

My question is :

Are `CustomerId` and `PK_Customer` 2 different names for the same primary key atribute?

Are they 2 different attributes that are copies of the same value?

And, either in name or in value, what is the use for this kind of redundance?

Comment: It's not really redunace.  It's just two ways of creating a primary key called PK_Customer on the CustomerId field.  Making a primary key on this field means that CustomerId has to be unique.  Both methods will achieve the same thing (although you have only specified one method as clustered).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Are CustomerId and PK_Customer 2 different names for the same primary key atribute?

No they are not the same. Actually they are two different objects (column != constraint):

```
CustomerId   -- name of column
PK_Customer  -- name of constraint
```

For example if you omit name of `PRIMARY KEY` constraint it will be autogenerated:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Customer (
    CustomerId INT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT PK_Customer PRIMARY KEY,
    FirstName NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
    LastName NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL);

SELECT name, object_id, parent_object_id, type_desc
FROM sys.objects
WHERE parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.Customer');

┌─────────────┬───────────┬──────────────────┬────────────────────────┐
│    name     │ object_id │ parent_object_id │       type_desc        │
├─────────────┼───────────┼──────────────────┼────────────────────────┤
│ PK_Customer │ 917578307 │        901578250 │ PRIMARY_KEY_CONSTRAINT │
└─────────────┴───────────┴──────────────────┴────────────────────────┘


DROP TABLE dbo.Customer;
CREATE TABLE dbo.Customer (
    CustomerId INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    FirstName NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
    LastName NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL);

SELECT name, object_id, parent_object_id, type_desc
FROM sys.objects
WHERE parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.Customer');

┌────────────────────────────────┬───────────┬──────────────────┬────────────────────────┐
│              name              │ object_id │ parent_object_id │       type_desc        │
├────────────────────────────────┼───────────┼──────────────────┼────────────────────────┤
│ PK__Customer__A4AE64D8749AE915 │ 949578421 │        933578364 │ PRIMARY_KEY_CONSTRAINT │
└────────────────────────────────┴───────────┴──────────────────┴────────────────────────┘
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d9c234db1422d940b3db1438970dff0a)**

> Are they 2 different attributes that are copies of the same value?

No, they are not copies at all. I guess that it may be confusing because of inline `PRIMARY KEY` definition. You could make it separate:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Customer (
    CustomerId INT NOT NULL ,
    FirstName NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
    LastName NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Customer PRIMARY KEY  -- out of the line
);
```

Or even on multiple columns(not possible with inline syntax):

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.InvoiceLine (
    InvoiceId INT,
    InvoiceLine INT,
    Description VARCHAR(100),
    CONSTRAINT PK_InvoiceLine PRIMARY KEY(InvoiceId, InvoiceLine)
);
```